# Changing font family of geom_text located inside a package

Tags: r, fonts, ggplot2, package

Using a R package called Likert which uses ggplot2 and I want to change the font family. In the package it looks like this:

```
    if(plot.percent.high) {
        p <- p + geom_text(data=lsum, y=100, aes(x=Item,
                        label=paste0(round(high), '%')), 
                        size=text.size, hjust=-.2, color=text.color)
    }
```

Was wondering how to change the geom_text from outside the package without knowing a lot of this information. For labels you can just use theme, but theme doesn't seem to work with this.

Currently

```
p = plot(lik) + theme(text = element_text(family = "Georgia"))
```

to change everything else to Georgia.

Comment: Probably an easier way but you could edit at the `grob` level

Comment: Definitely doable if I wasn't replicating the same graph for 50 times with different data.

Comment: Honestly I would just redefine the function at this point. You could [fork the github repo](https://github.com/jbryer/likert) and change whatever you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re comment, you can edit the `grobs` to change the `fontfamily` in the `geom_text` calls.

Code is wrapped in a function as you are wanting to replicate the graphs.

```
library(likert)

# example
data(pisaitems)
items28 <- pisaitems[, substr(names(pisaitems), 1, 5) == "ST24Q"]
l28 <- likert(items28)

# helper function - takes likert plot as input
# loops through the geom_text calls editing the font family
grid_fam <- function(p, fam="Georgia") 
                  {
                  g <- ggplotGrob(p)
                  px <- which(g$layout$name=="panel")
                  id <- grep("text", names(g$grobs[[px]]$children))
                  for(i in id)  g$grobs[[px]]$children[[i]]$gp$fontfamily <- fam
                  grid::grid.newpage()
                  grid::grid.draw(g)
                  invisible(g)
                  }
```

Plots

```
# original
plot(l28, plot.percents=TRUE, plot.percent.low = FALSE, 
                                             plot.percent.high = FALSE)
# with changed font
grid_fam(plot(l28, plot.percents=TRUE, plot.percent.low = FALSE, 
                                             plot.percent.high = FALSE))
```

There is most likely a simpler way to do this.

---

**EDIT** Update from comments: please feel free to improve

```
# initial plot
p <- plot(l28, plot.percents=TRUE, plot.percent.low = FALSE, 
                                             plot.percent.high = FALSE)

# Look at structure of returned ggplot - 
# it does not contain all the info used to generate the plot
str(p)

# g is a gtable which contains the grobs that make up the plot
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
g

# Get the list of parent grobs
g$grobs 

# layout details
g$layout

# we are interested in the grobs with layout name 'panel'
g1 <- g$grobs[[which(g$layout$name=="panel")]]

# have a look at the children within this gTree
childNames(g1)

# look at the structure - we are interested in the grobs with 
# name 'GRID.text.###'
# have a look at fontfamily and its position in the list structure
str(g1)

# extract the position of the grobs with names with 'text' in then
id <- grep("text", names(g$grobs[[which(g$layout$name=="panel")]]$children))

# check
childNames(g1)[id]

# look at grobs to be changed 
str(g$grobs[[which(g$layout$name=="panel")]]$children[id])

# loop through the text grobs changing the fonts
for(i in id)  g$grobs[[which(g$layout$name=="panel")]]$children[[i]]$gp$fontfamily <- "Georgia"

# plot grid obkects
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(g)

# the use of invisible returns the updated gtable if it assigned to a variable
out <- grid_fam(plot(l28, plot.percents=TRUE, plot.percent.low = FALSE, 
                     plot.percent.high = FALSE))

out
```

Comment: It's not elegant, but it works fine. Thanks a lot. Could you briefly explain how the function works just in the comments? It's a little confusing for me as an R beginner.

Comment: But i do agree with Gregor above, this is a long way to go about it. However, i would probably just make my own ggplot, which shouldnt be too difficult, rather than forking the repo.